# grep from file, print matched and unmatched

Tags: unix, sed, grep, pattern-matching, csh

I have a file, say input, containing patterns like below:

```
quantum_mech_.*
astrophysics_.*
geology_.*
economy_*
```

I have another file , say subjects, which looks like:

```
quantum_mech_[101]
astrophysics_[102]
geology_[203]
quantum_mech_[007]
geology_[205]
```

I want to grep each of the line from input file and search the file "subject" and output the first match only and also print "Not Matched" if the line is not found in subject file at all . So I am expecting an output like:

```
quantum_mech_[101]
astrophysics_[102]
geology_[203]
Not Matched
```

I know this is pretty old problem, but none of the methods seem to be working properly for me. I tried several variations of below code:

script.csh:

```
cat $1 | while read line
do grep $line ./subject | head -1 >> output
set VAR=$?
if ( $VAR==0 ) then 
        echo "Not Matched\n" >> output
endif
done
```

Run As:

```
    script.csh input
```

Any help/pointers using sed/grep/csh will be great.

Thanks and regards,

Comment: what shell are you using? `csh`? Your while loop has the wrong syntax for `csh`.

Comment: yes, I am using csh, in which i am not an expert :(
Can you please correct the code ?
Thanks

Comment: Do not use csh for scripting. Google "csh why not".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works fine in csh and bash.

```
for line in `cat $1`;
do
  grep -m1 $line ./subject || echo "Not matched"
done >> output
```

Thanks to dogbane's pointer, below is a better (and correct) way to do the same. The above also has issues when the lines have spaces in them.

```
while read line 
do
  grep -m1 "$line" ./subject || echo "Not matched"
done < $1 >> output
```

Comment: Even with the posted correction, it would fail for files containing backslashes or whose name contains spaces. Always write your while loops as `while IFS= read -r line` and always quote your variables, i.e. `"$1"` not `$1`.

Answer (score 1):

This will print each unmatched RE in addition to the text "Not Matched" so you know which REs weren't matched:

```
$ awk '
NR==FNR{ a[$0]; next }
{ for (re in a) if ($0 ~ re) { print; delete a[re] } }
END{ for (re in a) print re, "Not Matched" }
' file1 file2
quantum_mech_[101]
astrophysics_[102]
geology_[203]
economy_* Not Matched
```

It will work for any REs in file1 and any values in file2.

Comment: Thanks for reply. But it didn't give the same output as I got by using Vivek's code :( anywways thanks a lot

Comment: Awk is the right solution to your problem. Any time you find yourself writing a loop in shell you should take a minute to reconsider what you're doing as it's usually the wrong approach. If the script I posted doesn't produce the output you want then it would be well worth your time telling us what is wrong with the output so we can help you figure out what is wrong with your input files or the version of awk you are using.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way using `awk`:

```
awk -F "[.*[]" 'FNR==NR && !($1 in a) { a[$1]=$2 } FNR!=NR { print ($1 in a) ? $1 "[" a[$1] : "Not Matched" }' subjects input
```

Results:

```
quantum_mech_[101]
astrophysics_[102]
geology_[203]
Not Matched
```

Comment: stuck for too long in my shell. (file is big). yet I got it fixed through Viveks reply, thanks a lot for help